# Onclick Event not recording in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My google analytics events recently stopped working for an unknown reason. I didn't make any changes to my code and I'm pretty sure nobody else did as well. I checked through it and it looks like it should be working. Can anyone spot an issue with this?

First my header script:

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-?????????-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

Next the button which triggers the event:

```
<input name="button" type="button" class="button" onClick="return checkValues(true); ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'lead', eventAction: 'click', eventLabel: 'clickonform'}); " value="Submit" width="20px" />
```

And of course my Analytics settings themselves.

(3) Goal details

Category - Equals to - lead

Action - Equals to - click

Label - Equals to - clickonform

Value - Greater than - 0

Use the Event value as the Goal Value for the conversion

Maybe this is a friday thing and I am overlooking something obvious, but my mind just can't wrap around this, Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the value of "checkvalue(true)" before the event is sent. Try to send the event first, and then return.

Also, you are not passing in an event value, but your goal is configured to convert if the value is greater than 0. Might need to check on that.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting this:    onClick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'lead', eventAction: 'click', eventLabel: 'clickonform'}); return checkValues(true); "  The problem is that this doesn't work.

Comment: What does the "checkValues" function return? Try to narrow down the problem by determining if it's an issue with the order of the onclick code, or if it's just checkValues(true), or something else.